# RealmObject with @PrimaryKey only

Tags: android, realm

I have API that returns a list of objects. These objects have relations to another objects. But API returns only IDs for them. In order to get full object I have to use another API. For instance:

```
class Owner extends RealmObject {
    ...
    RealmList<Cat> cats;
}

class Cat extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

so when I receive list of `Owner`s I store them in database like this:

```
for (OwnerDto o : owners) {
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    ...
    RealmList<Cat> catsList = new RealmList<>();
    for (Cat c : o.cats) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.setId(c.id);
        catsList.add(cat);
    }
    owner.setCats(catsList);
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(owner);
}
```

but in this case all the cats' names are deleted if they were populated before.

Is it possible to create RealmObject with ID only in order to set relation, and fill it with date afterwords ? Or specify relation with Id only ? Or any other solution ?

UPDATE:
I came up with solution like this:

```
for (OwnerDto o : owners) {
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    ...
    RealmList<Cat> catsList = new RealmList<>();
    for (Cat c : o.cats) {
        Cat cat = realm.where(Cat.class)
                       .equalsTo("id", c.id)
                       .findFirst();
        if (cat == null) {
            cat = new Cat();
        }
        cat.setId(c.id);
        catsList.add(cat);
    }
    owner.setCats(catsList);
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(owner);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1917) I figured out that there is method `realm.objectForPrimaryKey(User.self, key: "key")` for swift but I did not fund analog in java version.

It would be nice to have in this situation something like `realm.getOrCreate(Cat.class, c.id)` method. Is there any ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I created a issue to tracking the enhancement. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2166

Comment: I've created a helper class to find objects by key (but it won't create them it not found, it will return null): http://stackoverflow.com/a/38136597/285678

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty rough to do that if you don't have the whole objects before you want to link them together, because you can't just store a `RealmList<T>` of primitives, only `RealmList<T extends RealmObject>`.

So your options are:

1.) have the cats in your Realm and then download the `Owner` into which you piece it together with realm queries.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.setCats(new RealmList<Cat>());
for(int i = 0; i < listOfCats.size(); i++) {
    String id = listOfCats.get(i);
    Cat cat = realm.where(Cat.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    owner.getCats().add(cat);
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

2.) have a `RealmList<RealmString>` in which you store the IDs.

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() { return value; }

    public void getValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

You'll probably need to use some ugly queries afterwards.

```
RealmResults<Owner> ownerOfCat = realm.where(Owner.class)
                                      .equalTo("catIds.value", catId).findAll();
```