# Proper way to get Realm object by its primary key in Android Java

Tags: java, android, realm

I wonder if there's a proper way to retrieve an object given its primary key in Realm for Android. I know the method `objectForPrimaryKey` does exists in Swift but there seems to be no such counterpart in Realm for Android. I really think that doing `realm.where(EventInfo.class).equalTo("id", eventInfo.id).findFirst();` looks like a lot of waste (at least it is not wrist-friendly). Am I missing some method? I'm Currently using Realm 1.0.1

Comment: Yes, that is a long line of code :) We have an open issue for it https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2166 . For now I think you need to use the long line or create a helper function for it.

Comment: @beeender I got used to have a `getObjectByKey<T>(T key)` in many ORMs (not that Realm is an ORM, it's more), so I thought there could be something already done in Realm. Maybe it could even be optimized. I would also suggest a method called .single() instead of findFirst() for cases in which a single object is expected (possibly throwing and exception if more than one is found). Should I add this suggestion on realm-java issues?

Comment: Yes, please! Keeping discussion in the github issue makes it much easier for us to track. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is why I have a Realm repository like this one (which I wrote)

```
public class CalendarEventRepositoryImpl
        extends LongRealmRepositoryImpl<CalendarEvent>
        implements CalendarEventRepository {
    public CalendarEventRepositoryImpl() {
        super(CalendarEvent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
        return calendarEvent.getId();
    }

    public void setId(CalendarEvent calendarEvent, Long id) {
        calendarEvent.setId(id);
    }

    public String getIdFieldName() {
        return CalendarEventFields.ID;
    }
}
```

and I inherit a method called `findOne(realm, id);` like

```
CalendarEvent event = calendarEventRepository.findOne(realm, id);
```

But yes, by default, it's `realm.where(CalendarEvent.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();`

Comment: I had this in mind, but then changed my answer because it's not a given that getId returns a long for all models, how do you deal with it?

Comment: I extend from `StringRealmRepositoryImpl` or `NoIdRealmRepositoryImpl` depending on the case

Comment: I don't like the repository pattern, I do prefer to use the ORM directly. In my experience repositories are more of a pain than any help. The ORM IS a kind of repository, as it allows access and query to the underlying data directly tied to the object model. Martin Fowler defined repositories as an "object that mediates between the domain and data mapping layers”. That's exactly what the ORM is for IMHO :-). So I'll probably subclass Realm itself and add the missing methods :-)

Comment: `public final class Realm extends BaseRealm {`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, it's final. Realized it earlier today. I've ended up creating a helper class named Find. I'm posting the solution right now

Comment: is this `O(1)` operation? it seems `O(n)` by the looks of it, but maybe `@PrimaryKey` is handled differently?

Comment: They have some form of index over primary keys so I'd assume something like O(log n)

Answer (score 6):

I've ended up creating a helper class for this. I'll be using it until the Realm team implement these methods. I've named the class `Find` (you can rename it the way you like, since naming things and cache invalidation are [the hardest things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)). I think it's better to use this than to call `where().equalTo()` passing the name of the primary key as a string value. This way you're sure to use the correct primary key field. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmModel;
import io.realm.RealmObjectSchema;

public final class Find {
    // shared cache for primary keys
    private static Hashtable<Class<? extends RealmModel>, String> primaryKeyMap = new Hashtable<>();

    private static String getPrimaryKeyName(Realm realm, Class<? extends RealmModel> clazz) {
        String primaryKey = primaryKeyMap.get(clazz);
        if (primaryKey != null)
            return primaryKey;
        RealmObjectSchema schema = realm.getSchema().get(clazz.getSimpleName());
        if (!schema.hasPrimaryKey())
            return null;
        primaryKey = schema.getPrimaryKey();
        primaryKeyMap.put(clazz, primaryKey);
        return primaryKey;
    }

    private static <E extends RealmModel, TKey> E findByKey(Realm realm, Class<E> clazz, TKey key) {
        String primaryKey = getPrimaryKeyName(realm, clazz);
        if (primaryKey == null)
            return null;
        if (key instanceof String)
            return realm.where(clazz).equalTo(primaryKey, (String)key).findFirst();
        else
            return realm.where(clazz).equalTo(primaryKey, (Long)key).findFirst();
    }

    public static <E extends RealmModel> E byKey(Realm realm, Class<E> clazz, String key) {
        return findByKey(realm, clazz, key);
    }

    public static <E extends RealmModel> E byKey(Realm realm, Class<E> clazz, Long key) {
        return findByKey(realm, clazz, key);
    }
}
```

Usage is straightforward:

```
// now you can write this
EventInfo eventInfo = Find.byKey(realm, EventInfo.class, eventInfoId);
// instead of this
EventInfo eventInfo = realm.where(EventInfo.class).equalTo("id", eventInfo.id).findFirst();
```

It'll return null if there is no primary key for the given object or if the object is not found. I considered throwing an exception if there were no primary key, but decided it was overkill.

I was really sad Java generics are not as powerful as C# generics, because I really, really would love to call the method as follows:

```
Find.byKey<EventInfo>(realm, eventInfoId);
```

And believe me I tried! I've searched everywhere how to get a method's generic type return value. When it proved impossible, since Java erases the generic methods, I tried creating a generic class and use:

```
(Class<T>)(ParameterizedType)getClass()
        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

And all the possible permutations to no avail! So I gave up...

Note: I've only implemented String and Long versions of `Find.byKey` because Realm accepts only String and Integral data as primary keys, and Long will allow querying for Byte and Integer fields too (I hope!)

Comment: `(Class<T>)(ParameterizedType)getClass()
        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];` this works only with type-parametric anonymous subclasses such as `new TypeToken<EventInfo>() {};`. It can actually also return `List<EventInfo>` for example, it's how GSON works for example. But a bit more difficult to type than `EventInfo.class`

Answer (score 4):

> Am I missing some method?

Nope. As beeender mentioned, it's not implemented currently. Progress/discussion can be tracked [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2166).

A helper function could look like this

```
public class Cat extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Cat getByPrimaryKey(Realm realm, int id) {
        return realm.where(getClass()).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    }
}
```

It a class-specific method here because each class could have a different primary key type. You have to pass a realm instance to it that you manage in the calling class.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Realm you can access to the primary key of your table using the schema of your DB in this manner:

```
private String load(Class realmClass) {
  return mRealm.getSchema().get(realmClass.getSimpleName()).getPrimaryKey();
}
```

I'm not very expert in annotation, I've tried to read value of `@PrimaryKey` at runtime by reflection, using `getAnnotation()` on fields, but values are always `null`, maybe because of `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)`.