# Realm find single object like MongoDB findOne in React Native and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

Is there any [MongoDB findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) like API in Realm React Native and Node JS? While searching I found similar question asked for Realm Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109905).

Here is what I'm doing right now to find a single object:

```
let realmResult = this.state.realm
      .objects('ModelName')
      .filtered('key_name = $0', key_value);

let data = realmResult.length ? realmResult[0] : null;
```

Is there any query API that allows finding a single object directly with query parameters?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Didn't try it latter, @David's answer should work, you can try that

Answer (score 1):

I can only talk about the Node API, but for Node there's only a function for retrieving a single object by its primary key. This can be done fitting your example like below.

```
let data = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('ModelName',key_value)
```

In case you don't have a primary key set up for that specific schema or in case you aren't filtering based on the primary key but based on another property, there's no function for retrieving only a single results mainly because there's no guarantee that there will only be a single result in this case.

Comment: Is the returned object reactive, e.g, will it trigger a re-render if it's modified?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the to other answer, but with reactive capabilities:

```
const data = useObject('ModelName', primary_key_value)
```

Check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/use-realm-react/#useobject